# The purpose of capacitors in a ZCD circuit of dimmer

Tags: power-electronics, isolation

I was searching the net looking for some high-voltage zero-cross detection circuit for a dimmer. Then I found this circuit on the net:

[image]

But on the first try after zero seconds, one of the 0.1 μF capacitors exploded. The capacitor was of the polyester type.

My first question is: why are the 0.1 μF capacitors needed, and second: if they are really needed, what sort of capacitor is suitable for this circuit? Should the preceding resistors be changed to 100 kΩ? The H11aa1's datasheet states that the diodes' forward current is 0.01 A.

Comment: I don't understand why my question got a negative point? It's not really clear to me, and maybe for many others.

Comment: There’s a renegade downvoter loose who maligns many questions without explanation. The good news is that downvotes aren’t scaled the same as upvotes - people REALLY need to hate you to mar your reputation.

Comment: The pulses you get are not placed at voltage zero crossing. The software must include this phase shift in the calculation.

Answer (score 0):

I ran a simulation of this circuit (probably with incorrect LEDs) and it seems to generate a half-sinusoidal current through each LED, the peak of which corresponds roughly to the zero crossing of the input waveform. this 90 degree phase shift is due to the capacitors being the dominant impedience in the circuit, hence they are **mandatory**. Try simulating it yourself:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fI9Noi.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Now your caps probably exploded because they wern't rated for the line voltage. I would go with at least 250V 0.1uf ceramic caps, and my gut is telling me to use a 400V part.

Comment: I have tried to omit the capacitors. And replaced the caps with wires. Also, I have changed the resistors to 100k ohm. Now I am looking for an oscilloscope to see if the pulses are shifted. Since the datasheet is really vague, the effect of the isolated part transistor is not clear. Moreover, The voltage I am working on is 220V 50hz, I choose 400V cap. and I thought that should be enough. but it seems I should selected a higher voltage toloreted cap. Thank you for response.

Comment: @V.Ajall It will certainly be shifted, or rather there will be no phase shift between the LED currents and the incoming voltage waveform. 100k each may be too much, the impedance of the caps was about 20k each when I checked - I'd expect two 50k's would be closer to what you need. You can compensate for this by assuming your zero crossings to be 10ms after the center of the pulse from the "ZCD" - simple algebra and timer work.

Comment: I prefer not to trust math but to trust physics. I have selected 100k ohms so the electric current through resistors would be 1 mA and the power would be 0.242 W so I can use 2W resistors.